# Why doesn't my contract compile?

Tags: solidity

I have the following contract, with just one function, which is to accept the ether sent.

According to the [docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#address), all addresses have a balance member. Why doesn't the commented line below compile then? The error on the offending lines are: *TypeError: Expression has to be an lvalue.*

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

contract testbalance {

     function() payable {
       address myAddress = this;
       myAddress.balance += msg.value; // doesn't work
       myAddress.balance += msg.value;   // doesn't work too
     }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't write to `myAddress.balance`, you can only read from it:

```
uint256 myBalance = myAddress.balance;
```

If you could so easily change the balance of any address, that would be a huge security flaw in Ethereum.

It seems like you're trying to receive money in your contract. You don't need to manually keep track of how much you have received. Ethereum does that for you. The value of `myAddress.balance` will change automatically.

Therefore, your function can be replaced with:

```
function() payable {
}
```

Because it doesn't do anything, you might as well remove it completely:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;
contract testbalance {
}
```